# ProgrammingError: relation "account_account" does not exist

Tags: django, django-authentication

I improved the registration form with django-user-accounts==2.1.0. Everything works fine on my local server, but on the heroku server I see the following error:

```
Django Version: 2.2.6
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "account_account" does not exist
LINE 1: ...nt"."timezone", "account_account"."language" FROM "account_a...
Exception Location: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py in _execute, line 84
```

I deleted the database and makemigrations/migrate again, it's did not help.

Relevant part of my settings.py:

```
import dj_database_url
db_config = dj_database_url.config()
if db_config:
    DATABASES['default'] =  db_config
```

Output of migrate command:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, my_apps, sites
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

DATABASE_URL also defined:

```
heroku config
=== Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:        postgres://bvki...longrul
```

Here I try to get table "account_account":

```
>manage.py dbshell
SQLite version 3.30.1 2019-10-10 20:19:45
sqlite> SELECT * FROM "account_account";
1||1|lt
2||2|en
```

In sqlite "account_account" exist!

But in the output of this command is not migration "account"!

```
>heroku run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ my-app... up, run.5012 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, my_app
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your `makemigrations` / `migrate` ran, because that is telling you that the table doesn't exist.

(1) Run `makemigrations` and `migrate`, and make sure you're running with the proper settings to run it on the Heroku server.
(2) Run `python manage.py dbshell` with your settings for the Heroku server and have a look at the tables that exist (`\dt` in PostgreSQL). Does `account_account` exist?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I supplemented my answer and included more information regarding your answer. Сan you describe in more detail (2) point? How can I do it with my settings for the Heroku server?

Comment: hey @lleviy did you solve it? I ran into similar problem.

Comment: @Dimanjan Yes, I needed to make migrations on the Heroku server, instead of doing this on the local server. Before that, my database on the heroku server was empty.
This command solve my problem: heroku run python manage.py make migrations